# RedirectVIew to an Internationalizated pattern in Django 4.0.3

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls

I am having problems using RedirectView inside i18n_patterns in my urls.py file. My current situation is this:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/', permanent=True)),
    path('adm/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('home/', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home')),
)
```

What happens is that if I connect to my site (for this example mysite.com) I am not redirected to mysite.come/home and django pop an error of missing pattern.

If I remove i18n_patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/', permanent=True)),
    path('adm/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('home/', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home')),
]
```

and I connect to mysite.com I am correctly redirected to mysite.com/home and the site works correctly. I have recently implemented i18n for the first time so I am not familiar with the topic. I tried splitting urlpatterns into two but got no results:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/', permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('adm/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('home/', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home')),
)
```